# Why blender keeps crashing while rendering this simple animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I'm running blender on Windows, and every time I try to render the animation to an .mp4 H264 video with audio blender crashes between the frames 300-400. This video has about 16,000 frames. Each frame takes about 4 seconds to render

By reading on other forums I found that sometimes the problem is that blender runs out of memory but I think this is no the case because blender is always using about 450MB of ram in my 8GB computer.

Here are my specs and some of the rendering settings:

- Intel Core i7 2.4GHz
- 8 GB Ram
- Windows 10
- Shading (Textures, Shadows, Ray Tracing, etc...) - All disabled
- Antialiasing 8x
- Render size: 1920 x 1080 at 30fps
- Threads: Auto (4)
- Tile size: (Tested with both 64 and 512)
- Video codec: MPEG-4 H.264
- Audio codec: AAC at 192 bps

  I haven't modified any other performance settings

The scene is a music video done with animated cubes with [GxAV](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/08/25/audio-visualizer-gxav/) and a plane with a particle emitter with 10,000 billboard particles

Is there a way to reliable render this with blender?

Comment: What is the Blender's version ? Probably this is a bug; try rendering those frames where it crashes manually (i.e. set frame in the Timeline to desired one and render). Is the render done with CPU or GPU ? Is this animation the only one where Blender crashes ?

Comment: Blender version is 2.7.6.0 and the rendering is done on the CPU. I think I found the solution, that is to render with console only and limit the number of threads to 2 instead of auto. If my render finishes correctly i'll post this as an anwser

Comment: If you are crashing, all the more reason not to render as a video format. Render as an image sequence and encode to video after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, that is to render with console only and limit the number of threads to 2 instead of auto with the command:

`blender -b "file name.blend" -a -t 2`

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Might it be due to a CPU problem? You might try out a stress test to confirm your CPU is working properly. Oh and you should mark your question as answered as well...